# Adding a new field or adding a new value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, database-design

If i have a field in my db which clarify the type of the application .

takes two values `0 or 1`

**0 for web app** and **1 for win app**

and now there is some requirement in my business:

> There are some win applications available to all users and some of
>   them belong to specific users .

---

What 's the best solution to handle this case .

adding new field to state whether it's public or private

or just adding new value to the same field say `2` to state `it's private win app`

Comment: please be more specific:
 what will be the base that your logic depend on to mark an application as available or not available for the requesting user?

Comment: I have some business rule that will clarify `the user permissions` but . generally i know i have public  win apps and not public win apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already it would probably be best to slip in a user, role, permission based security model to the database/system, thereby giving you the ability to specify a group of users that have access to a particular application, whether it be web or windows based

Answer (score 1):

I'd say add a new column next to your AppId called PublicIndicatior

Oh and be sure to have a lookup table so people can see what 0 or 1 means, and foreign key it to your data table

Lookup Table:

```
   AppTypeId, AppTypeDescription
   0, WebApp
   1, WinApp
```

Data Table:

```
  Id, AppTypeId, PublicIndicator
  1,0,1
  etc
```

Comment: As for reasoning, I figure it'll make future changes easier. Say you want to add a third type of App in a year from now. You won't need to know if they can be public or private when you add them to the lookup Table. You can wait to decide that until the instances are added to the data table

Answer (score 1):

As Pope suggested above (I +1 him), the best scenario is to add in a new user table (or tables for roles etc if possible) and then link to that through either a new foreign key, or using the appid (assuming it is on your table and unique). Then when the boss comes back 3 weeks later and say, "that's great, but now can we restrict App99 to just the Accounts Dept" you are not going back to the drawing board.